# Class and Object error; incorrect syntax

Tags: python-2.7

How would I be able to print each product? i.e, "I am a iPad, an Apple Product"

```
class Apple:
  def method1(self):
    print "I am a %s , an Apple Product" % self

iPad = Apple()
print ipad.method1()

iWatch = Apple()
print iwatch.method1()

iMac = Apple()
print iMac.method1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Apple(object):

        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
        def method1(self):
            print "I am a %s , an Apple product." % self.name

    iPad = Apple('Ipad')
    iPad.method1()

    iMac = Apple('iMac')
    iMac.method1()

    iWatch = Apple('iWatch')
    iWatch.method1()
```

This creates 3 instances of the class Apple namely iPad, iWatch and iMac. The **init**() method is called as soon as those 3 instances are created/instantiated. The string getting passed in then line where each object is instantiated, is the name that will be stored in    self.name for each object. 'Self' is just a place holder for the name of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The self parameter here denotes the object that calls the function. For your purpose, use:

```
class Apple:
    def method1(self,name):
        print "I am a %s , an Apple Product" %(name)

iWatch = Apple()
iWatch.method1("iPod")
```

Or another way of doing it is:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def method1(self):
        print "I am a %s , an Apple Product" %(self.name)

iWatch = Apple("iPod")
iWatch.method1()
```

Now, this will work.

This is actually a basic fact in Python Classes. Any method of a class takes atleast one parameter, which will be the first parameter in case of multiple parameters to the method, which is the object that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want each instance to have its own name that you can print. Something like this (I have named your `method1` "`describe`"):

```
class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def describe(self):
        return "I am an %s, an Apple Product" % self.name

iPad = Apple("iPad")
print iPad.describe()

iWatch = Apple("iWatch")
print iWatch.describe()

iMac = Apple("iMac")
print iMac.desc()
```